Realm test fails despite successful saving in Android (Kotlin)
I'm testing a Realm database in an Android app using Kotlin coroutines. I have a ConnectionsRepository with an isEmpty() method, and I'm writing a unit test that asserts behavior before and after saving a Connection object. However, the test fails even though logging indicates successful saving
Methods:
// ConnectionsRepository
override fun isEmpty(): Boolean {
    return RealmManager.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
        realm.where(Connection::class.java).count() == 0L
    }
}

suspend fun Connection.save(): Connection? = ConnectionsRepository.saveModel(this) 

override suspend fun saveModel(connection: Connection): Connection? {
    if (connection.createdAt == 0L) connection.createdAt = 
        DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).millis
    connection.updatedAt = DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).millis

    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        var savedConnection: Connection? = null
        RealmManager.getDefaultInstance().use { realmDb ->
            realmDb.executeTransaction { transaction ->
                Log.d("RealmTransaction", "Saving connection: $connection")
                savedConnection = realmDb.copyFromRealm(transaction.copyToRealmOrUpdate(connection))
            }
        }
        if (savedConnection == null) {
            Log.e("Error", "Connection was saved with error")
        } else {
            Log.e("Error", "Connection was saved successfully: $savedConnection")
        }
        savedConnection
    }
}

Test:
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class ConnectionsRepositoryTest : DatabaseTestCase() {

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun isEmptyTest() = runBlockingTest {
        Assert.assertTrue(ConnectionsRepository.isEmpty())

        runBlocking {
            Connection().setGuid("guid1").setId("1").setAccessToken("token4").save()
            advanceUntilIdle()  // Wait for coroutine completion
        }

        Assert.assertFalse(ConnectionsRepository.isEmpty()) 
    } 
} 

Logs:
04-04 16:55:47.713 22806 22836 D RealmTransaction: Saving connection: Connection(...)
04-04 16:55:47.716 22806 22836 E Error: Connection was saved successfully: Connection(...)

Troubleshooting:
I've verified that logging indicates successful saving of the Connection object.
I'm using advanceUntilIdle to wait for the coroutine to fully complete.
Question:
Why is my test still failing with an AssertionError? Could this be an issue with Realm caching or synchronization?
Please note:
I'm open to suggestions on improving the test or code structure.
If necessary, I can provide additional code snippets, such as RealmManager.getDefaultInstance().
Thank you in advance for any help!

I think an answer would need to be framed in reference as to what the purpose of the code is. In what way are you testing Realm? e.g. are you trying to throw an error? If not, what's the expected outcome?

@Jay I noticed that when running tests, I use different instances of the realm, and that's why the test (isEmptyTest) most likely does not pass

We don't know what RealmManager.getDefaultInstance() does - however, if it gets and returns a Realm the same way whenever it's called, it's actually the same Realm regardless of it being a different instance.

In my case, I was helped by refactoring my current saveModel method, specifically by using executeTransactionAwait. Here’s roughly what it looks like:
override suspend fun saveModel(connection: Connection): Connection? {
    if (connection.createdAt == 0L) connection.createdAt = DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).millis
    connection.updatedAt = DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).millis

    var resultConnection: Connection? = null
    RealmManager.getDefaultInstance().use { realmDb ->
        realmDb.executeTransactionAwait { transactionRealm ->
            resultConnection = transactionRealm.copyFromRealm(transactionRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(connection))
        }
    }
    return resultConnection
}

